# Sending don't fragment UDP packets at the server and receiving fragmented packets at the client

Tags: c, networking, ip-fragmentation

I've created a program in C that sends data with UDP packets.

Socket is made don't fragment using

```
int optval = IP_PMTUDISC_DO;
if(setsockopt(sd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_MTU_DISCOVER,&optval,sizeof(int))!=0)
{
    perror("setsocketopt()");
    return 0;
}
```

Checking with TSHARK at the server (debian 8 KVM virtualizied), for all packets don't fragment has been set:

[image: server sniffier]

But at the client, large packets receiving fragmented!!

[image: client side wireshark]

Then I figured something more wired. The IPv4 ID field has been set to 0!

I thought it might be because of the don't fragment effect (because no packet is going to be fragmented).

Then I started Openvpn program and sniffed its packets at the server but the packets had IPv4 ID != 0 while don't fragment was set.

Do you guys have any idea that why is this happening to me?!

Edit: Here is another sample of a large packet at server copy and pasted from tshark result.

```
Frame 1049: 1514 bytes on wire (12112 bits), 1514 bytes captured (12112 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: server_mac, Dst: gateway_mac
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: server_ip, Dst: client_ip
Version: 4
Header Length: 20 bytes
Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
    0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
    .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
Total Length: 1500
Identification: 0x0000 (0)
Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
    .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
    ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
Fragment offset: 0
Time to live: 64
Protocol: UDP (17)
Header checksum: 0xa52d [validation disabled]
    [Good: False]
    [Bad: False]
Source: server_ip
Destination: client_ip
[Source GeoIP: Unknown]
[Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 7554 (7554), Dst Port: 45376 (45376)
Data (1472 bytes)
```

Like you see, don't fragment has been set, while all packets larger than PMTU are receiving fragmented to client side.

This is a packet trace example of openvpn on the same server. like you see it at least has IPv4 ID calculated!

```
Frame 3749: 1455 bytes on wire (11640 bits), 1455 bytes captured (11640 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: SERVER_MAC, Dst: GATEWAY_MAC
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: SERVER_IP, Dst: CLIENT_IP
Version: 4
Header Length: 20 bytes
Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
    0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
    .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
Total Length: 1441
Identification: 0xcc96 (52374)
Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
    .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
    ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
Fragment offset: 0
Time to live: 64
Protocol: UDP (17)
Header checksum: 0xe252 [validation disabled]
    [Good: False]
    [Bad: False]
Source: SERVER_IP
Destination: CLIENT_IP
[Source GeoIP: Unknown]
[Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 19234 (19234), Dst Port: 46921 (46921)
Data (1413 bytes)
```

Comment: Those aren't the same packets. The first screen shot was for a packet with 175 bytes, but the second one is 1442 bytes.

Comment: Yes your right, they are not the same. That is why I wanted to check ipv4 ID filed to check for identical packets and found it 0! all packets including larger packets at the server side have don't fragment set.

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: Posted second sample as text

Comment: If you want to send UDP with Don't Fragment set, see answer (for c++, but the call is the same as c ): https://stackoverflow.com/a/63747510/5648845

MTU discover the way you use clearly also sets that flag, but it may not be a safe assumption that it will do what you expect. May not change anything, so I didn't give this as an answer!