# Set Don't Fragment flag using raw sockets for UDP

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I am writing a C++ program to allow me to set the DF flag (Don't Fragment bit) using raw sockets (MacOS doesn't support setting this) before sending out UDP packets.

I am relatively new to network programming and I'm looking for resources/code examples which do this.

I searched on SO, but all answers were mostly using `setsockopt()` which I can't really use in my case. Most of them pointed to using raw sockets, but there was no detailed answer on how raw sockets can be used to achieve this.

I have basic understanding of raw sockets. I am looking for an implementation of this which I can't find. Can someone please direct me to a code example/snippet or explain briefly how this can be achieved using raw sockets?

Comment: You tell it the packet you want it to send, and it sends it. You'll have to learn how IP and UDP work in order to understand how to do the first part.

Comment: Any links to code samples would really help understanding @user253751

Comment: If the packet is not to be fragmented, then what? Drop it if it's too big for the MTU?

Comment: @user4581301 Presumably -- and send back an ICMP "Fragmentation Needed" message. That's how Path MTU Discovery works.

Comment: What kind of "detailed information" do you need? There's a `flags` field in the IP header. Bit 1 is "Don't Frament". So just do `iphdr.flags |= 0x2;`

Answer (score 2):

Create the raw socket.

Enable access to the IP header by setting the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option:

```
int hdrincl=1;
if (setsockopt(fd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_HDRINCL,&hdrincl,sizeof(hdrincl))==-1) {
    die("%s",strerror(errno));
}
```

The flags are in the `ip_off` field of the `struct ip` header, which is declared in `<netinet/ip.h>`. There's a macro `IP_DF` for the Don't Fragment flag.

```
((struct ip*)&packet)->ip_off |= IP_DF;
```

Fill in all the rest of the fields in the IP and UDP header, and the UDP payload.

Send the packet.

Comment: Would I need to bind the raw socket to an address using ```getaddrinfo()``` and ```bind()```?

Comment: I'm not sure. Read a tutorial on raw sockets for how to use them in general.

Comment: Also, what if I am using "netinet/ip.h" which does not have iphdr and has struct ip instead. How would the setting of DF bit look then?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the correct fields of `struct ip`.

Comment: This is the way to set the DF bit for both IPv4 and IPv6 right?

Comment: Don't know if the structures have the same fields in both.